# Cannot ping bitbucket.org?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I suddenly cannot push to bitbucket server and reach bitbucket.org it just says `This site can’t be reached`. I tried pinging it and the ping could not find host bitbucket.org.

Tried the following:

1. DNS Flush
2. Clear chrome cache **(But I don't think this is necessary since other browsers also can't access bitbucket.**
3. Restart WiFi router

Still not working.

However, I can access bitbucket.org on my phone. Therefore, it's not a network-related issue.
I also don't have any antivirus installed on my Windows 10 laptop so its not that something is blocking it.

It's so annoying. Has anyone experienced the same problem before?
What are your solutions? Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I was wrong. I think its a network-related issue, I tried using VPN and now its working. **Still don't know how to solve the issue tho**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who encountered the same problem.

It seems that the problem is with the DNS.
In my case, I changed my local DNS to `1.1.1.1`.